# Porting MiG Layout To Codename One what's the right way to fit in margin?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, codenameone, miglayout

MiG layout was designed for Swing/AWT which only have insets, I'm now porting it to [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) which has more traditional padding/margin for every component. The port itself went smoothly however spacing between components isn't working quite as I would expect:

[image]

I'm assuming this is related to margin's which I think should be the equivalent of `Insets` but I'm not sure where they should fit in or why there is no spacing between the rows?

The full source code of the MiG layout port to Codename One is in our SVN tree which you can view online [here](https://code.google.com/p/codenameone/source/browse/trunk/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/layouts/).

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: This should be pretty familiar for anyone using MiG its the demo code from the home page: http://www.miglayout.com/ The question doesn't relate to a specific bug, its an architecture question on how to adapt the layout port between Swing (which uses Insets) to Codename One which uses Padding/Margin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insets are gaps around the borders of the container. `MigLayout` has `ins` constraint for this.

The spaces between the components are controlled by the `gap` constraint.
`MigLayout` has some initial gaps between components which are calculated 
specifically for the current platform.

So I assume it is a bug that is related to the port, not to the `MigLayout` manager.

Comment: Thanks. That's my basic working assumption the question is where in the port should I look? Any specific method/class?

Comment: The gaps are platform dependent. How about PlatformDefaults.java?
It currently set spaces for Windows, Mac OS X, and GNOME.
There is the setGridCellGap() method which is set for all platforms. Maybe your platform is not recognized and no gaps are set?

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising. I'll play around in that area.